# Redirect to anchor on page from controller

Tags: magento

I need to redirect to a page from a controller and scrolling to a particular anchor. I'm using the following in a normal Magento controller

```
$this->_redirect("shop/boxes#".$mainSku);
```

Assuming the `$mainSku` is 123, a trailing slash being added at the end so I'm being redirected to http://example.com/shop/boxes/#123/ for example. The trailing slash loses the scrolling effect to the anchor.

How could I overcome does (in the cleanest way possible)?

Answer (score 2):

How about just adding the anchor name outside the `getUrl` method?

```
$url = Mage::getUrl('shop/boxes').'#'.$mainSku;
$this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
```

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick!

```
$url = Mage::getUrl("shop/boxes#".$mainSku);
$url = substr($url, 0, -1);
$this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
```

Hope it would be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, the answer from Marius is the best solution, because the solution from Krt_Malta doesn't work if you use *arguments* or have *Add Secret Key to URLs* enabled.
(Sorry Marius, can't vote up jet.)

I took the original `$this->_redirect()` code and modified it, so that I can give it an anchor in a parameter.

Now I can use it like this:
`$this->_redirectAnhcor('*/*/edit', array('id' => $Id), '#products');`

```
/**
 * Set redirect into response with anchor
 *
 * @param   string $path
 * @param   array $arguments
 * @param   string $anchor
 */
protected function _redirectAnhcor($path, $arguments = array(), $anchor = '')
{
    $this->_getSession()->setIsUrlNotice($this->getFlag('', self::FLAG_IS_URLS_CHECKED));
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->getUrl($path, $arguments) . $anchor);
    return $this;
}
```